# Excel 2007 update reference when copying a row to another spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, reference, formula

I have two pre-filled spreadsheets ('main data' and 'variable prices') and VBA code that formats and copies one row from 'main data' to a 'results' sheet using some values from 'variable prices'.

On the first sheet a certain value is calculated using a cell in, say, BR column, when row is copied to the 'results' sheet that value is moved to another column, BY.

Something terrible happened and now the formula that calculates total on the 'results' is not updated and takes irrelevant value from BR column.

How to manually (I am guessing that when I put this together half a year ago the reference was updated automatically, but got destroyed when my boss edited/copied values or whole rows of data from other files, deleting the files after - I get "broken link" message now) set it back?

I hope this is legible. This is my only VBA experience, its operation is still somewhat of a mystery..

Thank you!

Comment: It's not too clear from your description what is wrong, but it seems like you have an Excel spreadsheet in which someone pasted some data linking to some other (now deleted) workbook(s).  Is there a programming question here? If yes, please include the relevant code.  If not, maybe superUser would be a better venue for this question.

Answer (score 1):

When you copy data as a formula and you want to keep referencing parts to the originating column/cell, you can "lock" the references. Example in a cell:

=A1, when copied two columns to the right would result in =C1 or
=A1, when copied tow rows down would result in =A3.

You can fix/anchor either the column, or the row or both in a formula by putting a $ in from of the reference.  =$A1 remains =$A1 even when copied two columns to the right. =A$1, remains =A$1, even when copied two rows down. =$A$1 will always stay =$A$1, wherever you copy this to.

Alternatively, if you only want the value (not the formula), use paste.value or 
cells(ref.target).value = cells(ref.org).value.

Oh forgot to tell you, when you highlight a cell address (A1) and you press F4, you can toggle between 4 stages from $A$1, $A1, A$1, A1